# One or two keyspaces in Cassandra for a different kind of data of the single application

Tags: cassandra

In my project I use Cassandra for analytics and MySQL to store data. I see that Cassandra could be good fit for data as well.

My question is: should I create a new keyspace for data or should I use keyspace that already exists an used for analytical data? What should I take into account when making such decision?

My stack is Python (Django) + pycassa, cassandra 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

Keyspace is simply a high level grouping of similar column families.  There are no hard and fast rules, and the most significant implications of either decision relate to the specific client library's API.  Personally, I create a new keyspace when I want a separation of concerns with my data.  It's somewhat analogous to creating a different database in a relational DB.